# Mailgun - Laravel retrieving attachments

Tags: laravel, attachment, mailgun

so I experimented this for hours. if you are using laravel, how do you download the attachments on the email from mailgun?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not the most elegant way but it works. I wasn't able to find something like this. so if you want to download the attachments on mailgun email.

**Getting the data from incoming emails**

```
$request->input('sender')
```

**Getting the METADATA JSON, I REPEAT JSON  of attachments**

```
  $request->input('attachments')
```

**SAMPLE METADATA of attachments**

```
'attachments' => '[
                    {
                        "url": "https://se.api.mailgun.net/v3/domains/sandboxcXXXXXXXX19a57487.mailgun.org/messages/XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX=/attachments/0", 
                        "content-type": "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document", 
                        "name": "Plan API end points XXXX.docx", 
                        "size": 53185
                        }
                    ]',
```

**Getting the file from the email**

STEP 1. json decode first the attachments

```
$files = json_decode($request->input('attachments'),true);
```

STEP 2. Install mailgun API using composer. (https://github.com/mailgun/mailgun-php)

Step 3. create a new instance of mailgun and use your API key, not the password.

```
$mg = new Mailgun('key-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx');
    foreach ($files as $file){
                $fileName = $file['name'];
                $content = $mg->getAttachment($file['url'])->http_response_body;
}
```

THAT'S IT, you can now download the $content , put in your cloudstorage, whatever.