# Mailgun error in Lumen - Argument 1 passed to Mailgun\Mailgun::__construct()

Tags: php, laravel, api, lumen, mailgun

I've installed Mailgun-php in my Lumen project. ( https://github.com/mailgun/mailgun-php )

via composer `composer require mailgun/mailgun-php kriswallsmith/buzz nyholm/psr7`

My codes something like this :

```
use Mailgun\Mailgun;
$mg = new Mailgun('key-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx');
```

error:

```
Argument 1 passed to Mailgun\Mailgun::__construct() must be an instance of Mailgun\HttpClient\HttpClientConfigurator, string given, ........
```

Did anyone solve this problem?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You haven't actually read the docs for the library you're using.

```php
use Mailgun\Mailgun;

$mg = Mailgun::create('key-example');
```

You need to call `Mailgun::create()`, not create a new instance of `Mailgun`.

It's worth noting that Lumen still supports Laravel's mail implementation, so you could still use that instead of requiring Mailgun directly (if that supported your use-case).

Comment: I'm trying to getattachment from mailgun inbound. I just compy the exact codes  in this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43824711/mailgun-laravel-retrieving-attachments

Comment: Well that code is wrong. Read the documentation from the Mailgun PHP GitHub repo to implement it with the latest version.